# See other registered facebookfriends on external site

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a new website where i would like facebook users to invite other facebookfriends, **but also see friends which is already registered on the site**.

Can anyone point me in the right direction where i can read about how to implement\develop this?

I know different games has had this option(blizzard etc) earlier.

My site is coded in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Friends who are already registered (meaning, authorized your App)**

You can either use the Facepile Social Plugin or use the Graph API with the /me/friends endpoint to read the friends manually.

- Facepile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile
- Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends

**Invite other friends**

In order to invite other friends, you can use the Request Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1